# Как выбираются вопросы для twitter'а?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

[Иногда](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/690856/revisions) в истории вопросов можно встретить плашку

> Опубликовано в Твиттере https://twitter.com/ruStackOverflow/status/884935632388280322 
>   произошло 2 дня назад

По какому принципу выбираются вопросы для публикации? Это происходит в автоматическом режиме, или кто-то вручную выполняет отбор?

Comment: скорее всего сообщения к которым много внимания, например большое количество просмотров за короткое время

Comment: Ссылки выбираются автоматически роботом, но конкретный алгоритм сказать сразу не могу. Постараюсь в каком–либо обозримом будущем его найти.

Comment: @alexolut, ещё б ответ туда))

Comment: @Qwertiy ответ там по классической схеме дан в комментарии :)

Comment: @alexolut, скорее тут) а там-то ссылка))

Comment: Тут не ответ, а прелюдия к ответу.